# Find parent based on child table keywords

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get the parents based on matching keywords using a child table:

```
AssetKeyword
============
AssetID (int)
KeywordID (int)
```

I'm trying to find the Assets having entries in the table, for example keywords 3 *and* 4 *and* 5.
I've tried subqueries and aggregates but can't get my head around it. Thankful for any help. Those fridays...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't very dynamic i guess..

```
select
    AssetID
from (
    select distinct
        AssetID,
        KeywordID
    from AssetKeyword
    where
        KeywordID in (3,4,5)
) t
group by
    AssetID
having 
    COUNT(*) = 3
```

Comment: Works. Thanks! Have a great weekend!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT a.AssetID, a.Col2, ...
FROM dbo.Asset a
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM AssetKeyword ak -- it doesn't matter what you "select" here
    WHERE ak.AssetID = a.AssetID 
    AND   ak.KeywordID IN (3, 4, 5)
)
```

This selects all parent records where there is at least one child with at least one of those keywords.

Comment: Thanks, but it isn't what I needed, as in OP, 3 **AND** 4... Cheers.